# Why is my UINavigationBar hidden behind the top navigation bar in iMessage?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout, uinavigationbar

I have an iMessage extension and I want to make a UI with a `UINavigationBar` on top. I made a `UINavigationBar` via a `UINavigationController` in the storyboard. The bar looks fine in compact presentation style but when I switch to expanded it gets hidden behind the top bar in iMessage. I have had this issue in the past and resolved it by setting the top space to top layout guide to 0. However, I don't think I can constrain a `UINavigationBar`. Any advice?